# Comparator not giving H when sine wave is positive

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, comparator

I have an LM311 with a **single supply** and an amplified signal which has AC 8Vpp and is centered at around 8V. In the schematic below, I represented the signal as a composition of 8V + 4sin(wt).

I want the comparator output to be H (~5V) whenever the signal is greater or equal to the mean of the V+ input (in this case, 8V). And L (0 V) if not. I thought of centering it at zero volts, and compare with Ground, but is just giving H, not varying between 0 and ~5V.

I also tried setting the BALANCE pin with voltages between 0 and 1.2V, but didn't work either, I just see the H output.

My goal is to know whenever the sine component of the signal is greater than the mean. Please recall that in my representation I divided the signal in DC+AC for explanation representation - in reality, the signals are merged, so I can+t just use V2 as one of the inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fATvbI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Difficult to post an answer with so many errors. R1 should be a straight connection, thus R2 becomes an unwanted load. Missing bypass capacitor on main supply rails, at least 470 uf.

Comment: You fixed the source issue, but you should still bias both inputs with a divider as Spehro suggests below.

Comment: @JohnD Why not just bias the reference to 8V and take off the capacitor in the non-inverting input?

Comment: @Sparky256 would you mind elaborating on the R1-R2 issue? I didn't understand why it became an unwanted load. I'm doing a voltage divider to have ~5V at the VCC of the LM311 so that the output has at max the same value.

Comment: @ludicrous Then use a LM7805 regulator instead of wasting wattage with resistors. You still need bypass capacitors for stable power.

Comment: The circuit you have posted works just fine for me, but D1 is not 1N4148 but a 5V Zener diode, and R8 is unnecessary. I have an LM311, put it on a breadboard, and at the moment of this comment, the circuit in the question works as shown. So, whatever you're doing is not what you're showing us on the schematic. Verify all pin numbers and such. Maybe you got a fake LM311? If you didn't buy the part from TI, DigiKey, Newark, Mouser, Jameco, Allied Electronics, Elfa/Distrelec, but rather from eBay or Amazon, get genuine chips and don't waste your time.

Comment: I imagine you need the LM311 due to its speed, otherwise LM393, LM2903, LM2901 will be cheaper and easier to get.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica  You could add  LCSC to your list next time you provide it.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit lacks a path for the bias current from the LM311 inverting input. Also the LM311 cannot work with voltages below zero so you should not be comparing it to GND.

You can bias each input with an independent voltage divider, say 10k/10k between the positive supply rail and GND. Leave the coupling capacitor there.

The state with no input will be indeterminate, but with a sine wave of less than a volt or two peak you should get good results. Higher that that or the input will go beyond the input voltage limits of the LM311. It might be optimal to use a bit different from 1:1 if you are close on that, but I'll let you read the datasheet and figure that out.

---

Here is an LTspice simulation of the changes, the input is a 1V sine wave at 100kHz.

[image]

Comment: So there's no way of bringing that to zero and testing if it's greater than "zero" (say, 0.1V) or not? With the proposed solution, why not just bias the reference voltage to 8V and take out the capacitor?

Note: I corrected the other issues with the circuit

Comment: Sure there is, you can have a negative supply voltage (as well as the positive one, of course) so that 0V +/- whatever peak voltage you are dealing with is within the range of the LM311 inputs. Bipolar supplies can often simplify circuits, after you pay for the bipolar supply.  An 8V input + whatever your peak is  would require a supply voltage quite a bit higher than 8V, and the LM311 inputs only go to around 2V less than the supply voltage. So if you have a 2V peak signal you'd want a 12V or more supply voltage.

Comment: The LM311 allows you to return the emitter to 0V if you have +/- supply voltages and would prefer an output that does not go below 0V. You can also pull it up to  less than the supply voltage so you could have +/-12V or +/=15V supplies and get a 0/5V output.

Comment: I changed the circuit with your suggestions, but could it is still not working - just giving the H output. I biased both inputs from the same voltage source with equal resistors. In V+ I have the AC signal input + Vbias, and for V- I have just the reference Vbias.

Comment: See above edit. If your input voltage is very low you might do better to use a single bias voltage source to avoid offset from resistor tolerances.